# Dúvida com cálculo da margem de lucro entre valores

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma consulta sql onde estou mostrando o valor de custo e valor de venda do produto, gostaria de mostrar a margem de lucro entre os valores de custo e venda, para a quantidade de itens vendidos

```html
select 
a.RAZAO_SOCIAL,
d.CODIGOCOMERCIAL,
d.DESCRICAO AS NOME_PRODUTO, 
c.ESTOQUE_ATUAL,
d.PRECO_CUSTO,
d.PRECO_VENDA,
e.QTDITENS AS SAIDA_PRODUTO,
(c.ESTOQUE_ATUAL + e.QTDITENS) as COMPRAS,
e.IDEMPRESA AS CLIENTE_VENDA,
(e.QTDITENS * D.PRECO_VENDA) - (e.QTDITENS * D.PRECO_CUSTO)  AS LUCRO_BRUTO,
C.DATA_ESTOQUE_ATUAL
from
TB_EMPRESA a
inner join TB_ESTOQUE b on a.IDEMPRESA = b.IDEMPRESA 
inner join TB_ESTOQUE_PRODUTO c on b.IDESTOQUE = c.IDESTOQUE
inner join TB_PRODUTO d on c.IDPRODUTO = d.IDPRODUTO
left outer join TB_MOVIMENTO_ESTOQUE e on c.IDESTOQUEPRODUTO = e.IDESTOQUEPRODUTO
where a.EMPRESA_CLIENTE = 'N'
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual a dúvida? Coloque na pergunta

Answer (score 2):

ai é matemática, (maior / menor) -1 * 100

exemplo, custo R$ 50,00 , venda R$ 100,00

(100 / 50) -1 *100 , -> ( 2 ) -1 * 100 , -> ( 1 ) * 100 = 100% ( resultado)

ou seja, comprou por 50,00 , vendeu por 100,00 , teve 100% de lucro.
o que vai ter que fazer é pegar o valor final das vendas, o valor de custo
total que teve para comprar esta mercadoria, depois é somente fazer a conta
acima, porem como você tem vários produtos e cada um com seu custo, ou calcula um por um, ou soma tudo e faz a conta acima, vai ter uma média.